# Use manage.py settings in Celery Config

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

I am following [Celery's documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) and am stuck at the following:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')
```

I'm following [Django Two-Scoops method](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/blob/develop/project_name/manage.py) of separating settings into .local and .production environments. Is there a way to have celery import whichever module I specify in my `manage.py` file so that I don't have to change `proj.settings` into `proj.settings.local (or) .production` too?

Comment: I can't see this line on the page that link you've pasted

Comment: I fixed the link and added clarification.

Comment: well, like it's said later you don't have to set this variable if you won't use celery command-line program. Or even when you will use it you can pass setting module while running it

Comment: To follow DRY, I want to import whatever settings file I have specified in my `manage.py` file into my celery config.